# Read visual properties (chart type, position, size, etc) of PowerBI dashboard

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have a online Powerbi dashboard. I want to create a cvs which contains a visual summary of all the objects in my dashboard.

This is what the export will look like (see below). As you can see it simply describes all the objects - their names, position, size, what page they are on etc.

[image]

How can I achieve this? I'm guessing there isn't built in way to do this? I will have to use custom code?

Answer (score 0):

In Report component we can use `activePage.getVisuals()` to get list of all the the visuals and its properties.

But we don't have such method for Dashboard component, although you can use Get Tiles In Group API to get details of tiles like: id, title, embedUrl, rowSpan, colSpan, reportId, datasetId.

**Reference:**

[Dashboards - Get Tiles In Group - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/get-tiles-in-group)